# QTP - Object doesn't support this property or method error

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error, qtp, hp-uft

I am not sure what's wrong with the below code.

```
    Set obj=description.Create()

    obj("micClass").Value="Link"
    obj("name").Value="Advertising Programs"

    Set totalnobuttons=Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").ChildObjects(obj)
    totalnobuttons.highlight
    print totalnobuttons.count

    For i=0 to totalnobuttons.count-1
        print totalnobuttons(i).GetRoProperty("name")
    Next
```

This gives an error "Object doesn't support this property or method error" during execution. I need to highlight the "Advertising Programs" program link using the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line:

```
totalnobuttons.highlight
```

is a culprit. You are trying to highlight the whole collection of **`Link`** objects. You cannot do that. Instead, remove that line and put that in your **`For...Loop`** like this:

```
For i = 0 to totalnobuttons.count-1
    totalnobuttons(i).HighLight
    print totalnobuttons(i).GetRoProperty("name")
Next
```

Comment: Glad to help... :)

Comment: I would prefer to use `For Each` for collections.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find collection object. Return type should be always array of objects.
Try to use advanced *for loop* to proceed. Find the code below:

```
For each button in totalnobuttons
    button.HighLight
    print button.GetRoProperty("name")
Next
```